# Trigger for three operation(Update,Delete,Insert) conversion error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create one trigger for insert,delete and update on *customers* table.
Trigger was created successfully ,however, I'm sure it contains many errors.
Here is my code of trigger

```
go
create trigger Onetrig
on customers
after update,insert,delete
as 
declare @log varchar(100),@name varchar(20),@activity varchar(20)
begin
if exists(select * from deleted) and exists(select * from deleted)
set @activity = 'Update'
set @name = (select c_name from inserted)
set @log = 'Record Updated in database '+@name
insert into logs
values(@activity,@log,GETDATE())

if exists(select * from inserted) and not exists(select * from deleted)
set @activity = 'Insert'
set @name = (select c_name from inserted)
set @log = 'Record Inserted in database '+@name
insert into logs
values(@activity,@log,GETDATE())

if exists(select * from deleted) and not exists(select * from inserted)
set @activity = 'Insert'
set @name = (select c_name from deleted)
set @log = 'Record Deleted from database '+@name
insert into logs
values(@activity,@log,GETDATE())
end
```

My task is to populate the *log* table with the activities of these three operations. when I perform any of the three operations it throws error of some kind of conversion.

`Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure Onetrig, Line 11
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

*customers* table has some records.
Here is the code of my *customers* & *log* table:

```
create table logs
(activity varchar(20),report varchar(20),Time datetime)
```

create table customers

```
(c_id int primary key identity(1,1) NOT NULL,c_name varchar(20),c_lastname varchar(20))
```

What conversion am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `report` to be 20 characters in `logs`.  But, you are inserting the string `'Record Updated in database '+@name` into it.  This has at least 27 characters.

Suggestions:

- Fix the length of the varchar fields.  You might as well make them much longer, even up to 8000 characters.
- When doing insert, *always* include the list of columns explicitly.
- Fix the first `if` statement to refer to `inserted` and `deleted`, so the logic makes sense.
- Put semicolons at the end of each statement.

Comment: Off course the length!
I have fixed all the suggestion you made, however its inserting three rows in Logs table for one operation. how do i fix that?

Comment: @AwaisShaikh . . . Put `begin` and `end` around the blocks after each `if`.

Comment: . You are the real MVP! Learnt so much in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's answer is very good.

I would like to add that in case of trigger, following lines

```
set @name = (select c_name from inserted)
set @name = (select c_name from deleted)
```

assume that there is *always* only one row inserted / deleted / updated. Which is wrong because DML triggers are at statement level not at row level.
I would change (for I/U/D) thus:

```
if exists ...
begin
set @activity = 'U/I/D'
insert into dbo.logs (... columns ...) -- <-- You should use the schema (default schema is dbo)
select @activity, 'Record Updated in database ' + x.c_name, GETDATE()
--                                      ^
--                                      |
--          ----------------------------------------------------------
--          The maximum length of dbo.logs.c_name (!?) column should be 
--          LEN('Record Updated in database') + 1 + MaxLength of dbo.customers.c_name column
from inserted as x -- or deleted
end
```